# Doubling radii of balls in groups of polynomial growth

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finitely-generated, infinite-groups, subgroup-growth

Let $G$ be a group of polynomial growth, let $S$ be a finite generating set for $G$ and let $B_n$ be the set of elements of $G$ given by words of length $\leq n$ in the generating set $S$. Is there an upper bound for the numbers $\displaystyle\frac{\#B_{2n}}{\#B_n}$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Context: I am looking for sufficients conditions for a group to have a certain kind of Folner sequence, and if this is true then polynomial growth groups would have such Folner sequences. In case anyone is curious, the Folner sequences I am looking for are left-Folner sequences $(F_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\exists\varepsilon>0$ $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist infinitely many values of $L\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there is a set $A\subseteq F_L$ which is a disjoint union of right translates of $F_N$ and satisfies $\frac{\#A}{\#F_L}>\varepsilon$. I call such a Folner sequence "self-covering".

Definition of polynomial growth I am using: A finitely generated group has polynomial growth if there exists a generating set $S$ and some big constant $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the ball $B_n$ defined above has $\leq N\cdot n^N$ elements.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Start by defining polynomial growth for groups.

Comment: Do you know about lower volume bounds for groups of polynomial growth? Do you know Gromov's theorem?

Comment: I don't know about lower volume bounds. It seems reasonable that one could use Gromov's theorem to prove one, but I asked in case it was a well-known fact (I am not an expert in these topics)

Comment: Gromov's theorem implies a lower growth bound of the form $an^N$. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: Yes, using that it's obvious. I think I see why that's true, I should write a detailed answer one of these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Gromov's polynomial growth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth), each finitely generated group of polynomial growth is virtually nilpotent. According to the Bass–Guivarc’h Theorem (see references in the same link) the for virtually nilpotent groups the growth function is $\sim n^d$ for some $d$ that can be computed in terms of the lower central series of the finite index nilpotent subgroup, meaning that
$$
a n^d \le |B_n|\le b n^d
$$
for all $n$ and some fixed positive constants $a, b$. From this, it is immediate that
$$
\sup_n \frac{|B_{2n}|}{|B_n|} <\infty.
$$